# scikit-learn Logistic Regression not learning And function

Tags: scikit-learn

What am I doing wrong here?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression as Lgr
Lgr().fit([[1,0,0], [1,0,1], [1,1,0], [1,1,1]], [0,0,0,1]).predict([[1,0,0], [1,0,1], [1,1,0], [1,1,1]])
```

This doesn't give [0,0,0,1] as expected. Giving [0,0,0,0]. predict_proba is returning all outputs < 0.5.

Comment: Logistic regression is not the right tool for this.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga [LogisticRegression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) (inspite of its name) is a classifier. :)

Comment: Maybe try hyperparamter optimization to check if the default parameters are affecting the quality.

Comment: @VivekKumar I understand that. That isn't what I was referring to. You can actually learn AND and OR, but XOR is not linearly separable, for example. Anyway, logistic regression is influenced by the amount of training data, the relative balance of positive and negative classes, etc. Try `Lgr().fit([[1,0,0], [1,0,1], [1,1,0], [1,1,1], [1, 1, 1]], [0,0,0,1, 1]).predict([[1,0,0], [1,0,1], [1,1,0], [1,1,1]])` And then try adding more positive examples. You'll find it starts predicting 1 when it should predict 0.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh yes. Sorry.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree, just using AND function as a simple example to test sklearn.LogReg out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the regularization parameter defaults to a value that causes an underfit. So I added C=10 to the constructor (C is the inverse so higher value means less regularization). Another change I am making is removing the first feature variable because a bias term is automatically added unless you pass "fit_intercept = False" in the constructor. Here is the working AND function:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression as Lgr
print(LgR(C=10).fit([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]], [0,0,0,1]).predict([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]]))
```